# SelectList -> how do I find the SelectedItem.Text?

Tags: drop-down-menu, selectlist

There are times where I would like to take the SelectedList and ask for the Text item that has been selected.  So using the example:

```
SelectList sl = new SelectList( new[]{
  new SelectListItem{ Text="one", Value="1"},
  new SelectListItem{ Text="two", Value="2"},
  new SelectListItem{ Text="three", Value="3"}
}, "Text", "Value", "2" );
```

How do I now ask the sl for the SelectedItem.Text ? I am surprised there isn't an is a method to do this, or atleast one I can see.  Any suggestions?  Do I need to IQuery or IEnumerate this in some fashion to make it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for the [SelectedValue-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectedvalue.aspx)

?

Comment: Not sure....  if tis was a List, I'd say sl.Items[selected].text;  or something like that.  For multi select I'd do for i = 0 to sl.items.count-1 do if sl.items[i].selected then ...

Comment: sry that i first now are answering i was on holidays. Have you tried to get your selected item by sl.SelectedValue ? It should be that what your trying